# How to compare node attribute against node

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to figure out how to do something similar to `if exists` in (node)

I have the following xml and on xls I´m trying to compare if available flags @id exists in contact/biographical/flags

```
<availableflags>
        <flag id="happy">Happy</flag>
        <flag id="curious">Curious</flag>
        <flag id="busy">Busy</flag>
        <flag id="expert">Expert</flag>
        <flag id="client">Client</flag>
        <flag id="manager">Manager</flag>
    </availableflags>

<contact>

        <biographical>
            <age>33</age>
            <flags>
                <flag>happy</flag>
                <flag>expert</flag>
            </flags>
        </biographical>
        <contact>
```

**xls**

```
   <xsl:if test="@id=contact/biographical/flags/@flag">
        <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked"> <xsl:text>{contact/biographical/flags/@flag}</xsl:text>
    </input>

            </xsl:if>
```

I have tried different variations of the if statement, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current context is a `flag` element then you need to navigate up the tree a bit to reach the `contact` element.  Also the `flag` in the contact section is an element, not an attribute

```
<xsl:if test="@id=../../contact/biographical/flags/flag">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </input>
</xsl:if>
```

But more generally, it looks like you're trying to render checkboxes for each available flag, with just the selected ones checked.  In that case it would be easier to make just the attribute conditional rather than the whole element:

```
<input type="checkbox">
  <xsl:if test="@id=../../contact/biographical/flags/flag">
    <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</input>
```